# Find the point on the plane $2x - y + 2z = 20$ nearest the origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What I did was use the distance formula from the plane to the origin, found the normal vector, and found the unit vector of the normal vector. I multiplied the unit vector by the distance to get the point (and it satisfies the equation). Is this correct?

Is there a way of doing this using optimization (i.e. local min/max)?

Comment: Yes, you can.  It will be more work that what you did.

Comment: Or you can just notice that the normal is $(2, -1, 2)$ and find where the line $(2, -1, 2)t$ intersects your plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds right.

Yes, you can do this by minimization. First write down the distance of a general point from the origin (hint: it is simple). Then you want to minimize that function subject to the constraint given by the plane.